# python not running from command line

Tags: python, command-line, ubuntu-11.10

I have Ubuntu 11.10, and I have always run python just fine. However I have run into a problem. I was trying to get jpeg working with PIL and I did something and now python won't run from the command line. Earlier it said change PYTHONPATH AND PYTHONHOME and also gave me and ImportError: No module named site. So I set PYTHONPATH AND PYTHONHOME to /usr/local/lib/python2.7 and now I only get the 'No module named site'. So still python not working from command line. I've found out a little bit about site from http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/site/, but I cannot figure out how to remedy this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Unset those variables and start over?

Comment: How did you install PIL?

Comment: I unset and tried python again. Now Iimport site 'm back to 'could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>'  'could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>'  'consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]'  'ImportError: No MOdule Named site'

Comment: @burhan I had previously installed it from source downloaded from online. Then I tried to uninstall it and reinstall with pip install Imaging per <http://obroll.com/install-python-pil-python-image-library-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/> because I was getting no JPEG support

Comment: You might want to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` to fix the system Python.

Comment: @burhan I tried the reinstall and I'm still getting the same errors. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: You have more than one version of Python on your system, and one is broken. Either expand your question detailing the `did something` part, or the commands that you typed so we can help. Like this everyone is guessing.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  THis should be on http://superuser.com/

Comment: This still is programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/dir`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PYTHONHOME`?